# Simulate data based on conditional logistic regression

Tags: r, conditional-statements, logistic-regression, survival-analysis

I would like to run a simulation study on **conditional** logistic regression models. My model is the following:

log(p/(1-p)) = b_1*sex + b_2*exposure (1)

and I fit this in R:

```
library(survival)

model_clogit <- clogit(case ~ sex + exposure + strata(set), data = data)
```

Returning in equation (1) I would like to use the right part, compute log(odds) and based on the log(odds) calculate the probability of being a case, given that it belong in the ith stratum. So what I basically did is anti-logit the odd to get a prob = probability and I divided this prob with the sum(prob) per stratum.

Now since each of my strata have to contain only one 1, I sampled an 1 per stratum with weights based on the prob/(sum(prob)). I performed this procedure several times and I compute the distribution of the sex and exposure coefficient via clogit, with the true ones. Although I get a fair estimate for the exposure, the sex seems to be far of the true.

Does anyone have any idea why? Is the any more efficient way to simulate data from a conditional logistic regression model?

Thanks,
Akis

Comment: why don't you try the predict methods that come with the survival package? check the documentation, there are several ones, i assume you would need predict.coxph as clogit calls coxph

Comment: In general what one should do in this case is type

    class(model_clogit)

And if it says "glm" use `predict.glm`, else look in the documentation for the apropiate predict method. 


  [1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf

Comment: I can predict probabilties I assume, but what Im actually interested to do is have a sample of 0s and 1s (only one 1 per stratum) based on these probabilities. My approach as described above is probably false since the sex coefficient is way of. Do you have any idea of how I could draw a random sample from a bernouli type distribution given that the sum per stratum is 1?